# GNU sed remove spaces from digit number in text file

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following bogus data:

```
Dominik Dryja|4111 2386 0873 0189|0315
Laivonen Eero|5111 0620 0750 8041|0813
Jukka Valimaa|5111 6500 0489 0035|0415
Rafael Diaz de Leon|4111 3036 6209 4796|0516
Mr Jonathan Bird|4111 6150 0291 7415|0215
ERRANTE VINCENZO|4222 6111 0038 6639|0114
YOSHIO MOTOKI|5222 3200 0374 7129|0513
I. A. VLACHOGIANNIS|4333 0115 6936 2003|0315
Soumya Kanti Deb|4333 0590 0165 4877|1019
WU KE ZHAN|5444 8213 7236 0431|0716
```

I try to strip the space ONLY from the digit number to look like this:

```
Dominik Dryja|4111238608730189|0315
Laivonen Eero|5111062007508041|0813
Jukka Valimaa|5111650004890035|0415
Rafael Diaz de Leon|4111303662094796|0516
Mr Jonathan Bird|4111615002917415|0215
ERRANTE VINCENZO|4222611100386639|0114
YOSHIO MOTOKI|5222320003747129|0513
I. A. VLACHOGIANNIS|4333011569362003|0315
Soumya Kanti Deb|4333059001654877|1019
WU KE ZHAN|5444821372360431|0716
```

Tried `sed -r '#|([0-9]{4})\ ([0-9]{4})\ ([0-9]{4})\ ([0-9]{4})|#\1\2\3\4#g'`
for some reason without success. Any idea where I'm mistaken?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your sed:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\) /\1/g' inFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's always a single space between numbers:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/g'
```

Works with your example.
The code is simple - remove all single spaces if they happen between two digits.

Comment: Yes, it works but my digit pattern is "|dddd dddd dddd dddd|", your answer will remove the single space between "dd dd" too, and that I don't want.

Comment: Your example doesn't have such patterns, so I thought any space between digits should be removed.

Comment: How doesn't it? "|4111 6150 0291 7415|"

Comment: It doesn't have patterns where spaces should be kept.